# Do modern cpus skip multiplications by zero?

Tags: cpu, instructions, multiplication

I would like to know if current cpus avoid multiplying two numbers when at least one of them is a zero. Thanks

Comment: How would it "skip" a multiplication? If it gives 0 as the result, no matter how fast it does so, it has in effect done the multiplication.

Comment: Megan Wachs mentions this question in her [RiscV keynote](https://youtu.be/vCG5_nxm2G4?t=1545). She also mentions a great point in there: this would be *terrible* for security, as it would make many algorithms open to timing attacks. It opens a side channel, where many calculations would run shorter than others, when crossing such "zero point".

Answer (score 1):

This varies widely depending on the CPU and (in some cases) the type(s) of the operands.

Older/simpler CPUs typically use a multiplication algorithm something like this:

```
integer operator*(integer const &other) {
    unsigned temp1 = other.value;
    unsigned temp2 = value;
    unsigned answer = 0;

    while (temp1 != 0) {
        if (temp1 & 1) 
            answer += temp2;
        temp2 <<= 1;
        temp1 >>=1;
    }
    return integer(answer);
}
```

Since the loop executes only when/if `temp1 != 0`, the loop obviously won't execute if `temp1` starts out as 0 (but as written here, won't attempt any optimization for the other operand being 0).

That, however, is fundamentally a one bit at a time algorithm. For example, when multiplying 32-bit operands, if each bit has a 50:50 chance of being set, we expect approximately 16 iterations on average.

A newer, high-end CPU will typically work with at least two bits at a time, and perhaps even more than that. Instead of a single piece of hardware executing multiple iterations, it'll typically pipeline the operation with separate (albeit, essentially identical) hardware for each stage of the multiplication (though these won't normally show up as separate stages on a normal pipeline diagram for the processor).

This means the execution will have the same latency (and throughput) regardless of the operands. On average it improves latency a little bit and throughput a lot, but does lead to every operation happening at the same speed, regardless of operands.

Answer (score -3):

I would expect that a modern desktop CPU would have such a thing in it.