# will x86 cpu perform an early end of multiplication when detects a zero-operand?

Tags: cpu, hardware

================Update=======================

Seems duplicate of [Do modern cpus skip multiplications by zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332670/do-modern-cpus-skip-multiplications-by-zero)

But please allow me to reserve this post, because I didn't search out that post before my publish. And allow me to post my test result in the *answer area*.

==================Original Post=================

Take this function as example:

```
int mul(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    return a*b*c*d;
}
```

When cpu enters this function call:

```
int result = mul(0, 1, 2, 3);
```

(assume we don't allow the compiler do any optimization and the machine code appears exactly as the program order.)

I know nowadays x86 CPU has *out-of-order execution*, will it perform an early end of multiplication when he found he got a zero-operand?

Thanks!

Comment: It might. It might not. Depends on implementation.

Comment: Which CPU? You need to talk about a specific one, otherwise this question is not answerable. Also not all CPUs perform out-of-order execution (most x86-64 architectures do, but RISC usually don't)

Comment: [this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332670/do-modern-cpus-skip-multiplications-by-zero).

Comment: @UnholySheep OK, i have update.

Comment: All current x86 µarchs have fixed-time multiplication.

Comment: The test is most likely slower than the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a modern x86-64 CPU will not stop multiplying numbers just because one of them is zero.  Out of order execution isn't going to prevent any of the instructions from running, it just might allow some to be executed well, out of order.

This is easy to verify using the code you wrote.  Let's call it `multiply.c`:

```
int mul(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    return a * b * c * d;
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1e8; i++) {
        int result = mul(0, 1, 2, 3);
    }
}
```

Firstly verify that the code doesn't run any slower when the '0' is replaced with a '1':

```
gcc multiply.c -O0
time ./a.out

real    0m0.387s
user    0m0.378s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Re-running after changing the 0 to a 1 resulting in a real time of 0.384s, no statistical difference.

Next take a look at what assembly is being generated by gcc:

```
gcc -g -c -O0 multiply.c
otool -tvVX multiply.o

...

_mul:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    %edi, -0x4(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -0x8(%rbp)
    movl    %edx, -0xc(%rbp)
    movl    %ecx, -0x10(%rbp)
    movl    -0x4(%rbp), %ecx
    imull   -0x8(%rbp), %ecx
    imull   -0xc(%rbp), %ecx
    imull   -0x10(%rbp), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    nopw    %cs:_mul(%rax,%rax)
```

You can see the three separate multiplies, so they aren't being compiled away or anything of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

@Douglas B. Staple

Thanks for you benchmark. I also did a similar test.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"../base/benchmark.h"

#define MAX (100 * 10000)
int product0;
int product1;
int zero = 0;
int one = 1;
int main(void){
    TSTAMP_INIT();
    long time0, time2;

                                                            TSTAMP();
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        product0 *=  zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero * zero ;
    }
                                                            TSTAMP(&time0);
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        product1 =  one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one * one ;

    }

                                                            TSTAMP(&time2);
    printf("%ld %ld\n", time0, time2);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and Run:

```
$ gcc -o t t.c ../base/benchmark.c -O0
$ ./t
84828 74827
```

The time unit is `us`.

I have checked the assemble code, it's not optimized.

The reason I use a long multiplication expression inside the loop is that, I want to reduce the time cost proportion occupied by *loop* instruction.

*It seems that the first loop body cost a little more time(84838us), i think it's because of the warm-up phase of CPU cache. I have reverse location of two loop bodies and get a similar result: still the former cost a little more time.*

So I can get a same conclusion as you, and as other friends stated, multiplication on `x86` is time-fixed.